# errors with import library in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am facing a strange error. I have installed pyrenn module with pip install in conda environment and solved an ANN problem successfully. But when I restarted the kernel in jupyter or spyder, I am not able to even import the module which shows error:  module 'pyrenn' has no attribute 'CreateNN'. But it definitely has the module and it worked last time.[image]

what may be the possible problem?

Comment: Rename your your current file and directory to something other than the name of the library, you're importing yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your screenshot it shows a path `~/ANN study/pyrenn/pyrenn.py`. So not only you are creating a conflicting folder name `pyrenn` you are also creating a conflicting importable file `pyrenn.py`.

Follow the thumb rule of not naming the folders and your files which conflict with modules that you will uses or are existing.